# How to set Claimtypes.NameIdentifier as a UserId value to multiple rows in other DB Table for new user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, blazor

When new, authenticated user logs in, i want to set his UserId from AspNetUsers table to my Tasks table as a UserId to each Task row. In my Tasks table is a set of six task rows as TaskId, UserId, TaskDescription, Count. In frontend each task has a button for to increment count how many times the user has accomplished each task. In my TaskController method following code sets the UserId as expected, but only to the last row of tasks.I have tried "foreach" loop but obviously I am doing something wrong.

```
private string GetCurrentUserId()
{
   return HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
}

private string GetUserId()
{
   return User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
{

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Tasks>> GetTasks()
{
   var tasks = _context.Tasks
       .Where(u => u.UserId == GetCurrentUserId())
       .ToList();

   if (tasks.IsNullOrEmpty())
   {
       Tasks tasks1 = new Tasks
       {
          UserId = GetUserId()   //this sets the UserId but only to the last task on the list, which 
                                 //frontend also shows only.I want to show the whole set of 
                                 //CurrentUsers tasks. Foreach loop gives me nulls, but I am a 
                                 //student and maybe not doing it right.
       };                         

       _context.Add(tasks);
       _context.SaveChanges();
   }
     return tasks.ToList();
}
```

Comment: You will have the same userid value in all the the time for the currently logged in user. Why you want to loop?

Comment: With my code only the last task of the set of six  is shown in frontend because for some reason it sets the userId only to the last task when user logs in for the first time. It should set it to all six tasks so that the frontend would show all six where the UserId = CurrentUserId. I think that with loop i could make  set it to all six, but something went wrong and it just returned tasks = null.